# get status and version of an epic

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I  extracted via a rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/epic the epics belonging to a board.

The epics that i get from the api do not have the status and the version, is there another method to get the epics with their status and version?

Example of an epic that i get from the api

```
{  
"id": 162380,
  "key": "BCUSP-1",
  "self": "xxxx/rest/agile/1.0/epic/162380",
  "name": "1. Référentiel PS-CE",
  "summary": "Référentiel PS-CE",
  "color": {                             
"key": "color_9"                  
   },
  "done": false        
}
```

Comment: This should give you a list of epics on the board then I think you'll have to loop through each of the results, get the "self" key, then use the REST API to grab the epic from that link - e.g. from "xxxx/rest/agile/1.0/epic/162380". I *think* that should give you the status and version.

Comment: Why not get the epics through the filter that is populating the board?